# Spacing issue between letters while converting Word to PDF on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, ms-word

I am having a word document(docx) of urdu text in Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Font. And in word its showing 10 pages file but after exporting into PDF its showing 11 pages pdf file becuase every letter contains extra space.

Can anyone please provide information ?

Edited:

Please download the file from 
[File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3d402970700d51b20812c601e64b5ecc20170504065208/cd3063)

Comment: how are you exporting the file? maybe there is something in the implementation about that space?

Comment: Something similar can happen when printing a MS Word document on different printers. MS Word does not guarantee a stable layout across different output media.

Comment: Can you share the document? I'd guess it is a font or encoding issue.

Comment: For me, both Word and PDF version contain 9 pages and look visually identical. What Word version are you using to create the PDF?

Comment: Version 2013 @DirkVollmar

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the XML formatting of Word. When any text is pasted into Word (while the font is Jameel Noori Nastaleeq) Word places extra formatting in between the words. That formatting shows fine in Word however in when the file is converted into PDF the extra space becomes visible. When the text is merely typed in Word, the formatting is applied to entire paragraphs rather than words. That is why a typed document doesn't contain the extra spaces.